# Facebook business login error: It looks like app is not available Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook, facebook-authentication

Getting error on facebook login
App type is Business

app created in other category see below
[image]

My app is in Live mode
and allowed permissions is
[image]

error is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please create the **Configuration** in **Facebook Login for Business** section with some permissions. Then you those permissions inside the login permissions. I'm using React-Native but I think flutter also provides the same method

```
const loginResult = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
        'email',
        'instagram_basic',
      ]);
```

Comment: Not working ...